# Python Search CSV with Regex and export result to different CSV

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, csv

I am using Python3 with the regex and csv module loaded, and trying to create a script to pull a string out of a csv with a regular expression and then export the result it to a different csv. The idea is i have a csv that someone gave me that has a single columned and for some reason has a cell with way to much infomation in it. including quotes, line return, and bunch of other garbage. I only need a very small section of each cell.

My script is able to print the result but for some reason the following script returns the error `"AttributeError: 're.Match' object has no attribute 'write'"` when trying to writerow to the csv.

**I want to extract a single string from each cell of the csv and then export it to another csv.**

```
import csv
import re

with open('Failed.csv',mode='r') as csv_file, open('result.csv', mode='wb') as csv_result:
     csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file)
     writer=csv.writer(csv_result, delimiter=',')
     for row in csv_reader:
            pattern = 'Computer Configuration\\.*\n*.*'
            currentrow = row[0]
            found = re.search(pattern, currentrow) 
            if found:
                print(found)
                writer.writerow(found)
```

Answer (score 0):

The method `re.search` returns a `Match` object that you can't use directly. If you want to retrieve a valu from the row you may use a group

```
value = "foo123"
pattern = "foo(.*)"
match = re.search(pattern, value)

print(match, type(match))  # <re.Match object; span=(0, 3), match='foo'> <class 're.Match'>
print(match.groups())  # ('123',)
print(match.group(1))  # 123
```

Comment: weird part is when i do print(match.groups()) it just returns ()

Comment: @Zygodactyl you need to use parenthesis in your pattern to create matching groups, you may read about groups, you’ll find easily details ;)

Comment: yeeep that was it i missed the parenthesis in the pattern that was dumb.

Comment: Also had to change open for the second file to w from wb